# How is it possible for scammers on YouTube to use the same exact username as the author of the video?

Tags: google, scam

Recently, there has been an absolute massive flood of scammers on YouTube videos related to Bitcoin. Their "trick" is to use the exact same username and profile picture as the person who uploaded the video, for example "MMCrypto", then making spammy comments/replies in the comments section, pretending to be the author of the video.

Of course, the actual author would get a special styling and a little "verified" icon (if they are verified), but still, I'm talking about the username being identical.

At first, I assumed that it was a "Unicode trick" where they use similar-looking glyphs, but that is not the case.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylkiET_iCPc (click one of the "View 2 replies" links to see a scammer comment)

If you search that webpage for "BitBoy Crypto" and select "highlight all", it marks both the scammers' posts and the video uploader username, indicating that they are identical. So they are not using "similar glyphs".

I guess they could be using some sort of "invisible character" trick, but you'd think that YouTube if anyone would be on top of that. It's the only thing I can think of, but it doesn't seem realistic.

How are they doing this?

Comment: You have assumed some tricky thing has happened, so you didn't think that the simplest answer was possible and didn't search or test for that. This is not a security question at all. This is just how YouTube works. https://www.google.com/search?q=another+youtuber+has+the+same+name

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube *channel name* is not a username, but a *display name*. They are not unique, so one does not have to perform any tricks to get a matching display name. For normal users without a [brand account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690) the display name is [linked with the Google Account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cchange-your-channel-name-and-description).

Those [verification badges](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046484?hl=en) are not about protecting channel names, but an extra feature for channels with more than 100,000 subscribers.